# Game engine development question

Tags: c#, c++, performance, opengl

I am thinking of making a simple game engine for my course final year project. I want it to be modular and expandable so that I can add new parts if I have time. For example I would make a graphics engine that would be completely independent of the other systems, once that was finished I could add a physics engine etc.
I would also want to make a tool set to go with this engine. For the tools I would like to use C# but I am not sure about the libraries. My question is, if I want a C# GUI program, can I reference a library written in C++? Also would there be any performance problems etc. if I made some of the libraries in C# but wanted to use them from a C++ game.

I would like to avoid C++ as much as possible, my experiences have shown that development time can be a lot higher for a project over that of using C# or Java etc. My graphics development would be in OpenGL, this is all I have been taught. We have only done this in C++ but I have seen that projects such as [SharpGL](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/openGL/sharpgl.aspx) allow for the development with C#. Is there any performance issues with this. I am not looking for a blindingly fast, top graphics game. It will most likely be something simple to show my engine working. My engine probably won't be that great either as I only have a year and am working on my own.

Any advice on this would be appreciated. I am still really in the planning stages so it wouldn't be too much work to completely change what I want to do. I would just like to preempt any major problems I might have.

Thanks

Comment: +1 Nice project. Good luck with it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you can pull this off even under a relaxed set of goals, you're set for a great project. First, you need to get a grasp of scope:

- How long do you have to work on the project?
- How many people are working on the project?
- If you can only create one "piece of the pie" on your own, which one would you pick? Use this to establish a working plan to make sure if you don't get as far as you'd like, you still have enough to make the work show as a great project.

A game engine is a big development task. A game engine with a toolchain is an enormous development task. In a lot of ways, choosing a smaller but more challenging task is preferable because it shows higher-level thinking about problem solving, which is greatly preferred by academics - double that if you are CS and not [Area of] Engineering. Since you are working in managed languages, things you may want to consider are:

- Expressing gameplay logic (rules of the game) in a clean manner so as to provide an efficient and reliable path from designer->developer->tester. If you want, this could absolutely include the manner in which you describe the rules (Custom editor? Code API? DSL?)
- Game AI has no shortage of extremely challenging problems.
- Physics and graphics are interesting and I believe managed languages will eventually be used in these areas, but you may find yourself a bit more limited in your ability to solve these problems. If I were going to work in this area now, I would be trying to answer: "If I could use a managed language for writing [graphics|physics] code without hurting performance, what kinds of [language|runtime] features make the most difference in improving the expressiveness, correctness, maintainability, and reliability of the resulting programs." This goes *way* past simply having garbage collection and pointer safety.

Answer (score 4):

You should look into [XNA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_XNA). It performs quite well, and from what I've heard, is quite easy to work with.

About referencing C++ code from C#: It's perfectly doable, though it will take some effort from your side to get it right. C++/CLI can work as an intermediate wrapper or you can use P/Invoke. Just remember that C++ is unmanaged and that you will need to do some manual garbage collection, which can be somewhat icky in a managed environment like .Net. Perfomance in the C++ -> C# bridge is okayish, but I'm unsure how it will perform if you need do 100.000 calls to a math-library each second. I guess a small test would be good.. I'll see if I get time to do this later today, though I somewhat doubt it :)

Comment: I've used XNA for other project before but don't really want to use it for this. The problem is that anything that XNA handles I won't get any marks for and a lot of what it handles is things I know how to do so I would prefer showing that I can do by doing it myself. For example, loading resources such as models/textures from a file.

Answer (score 3):

When creating a graphics engine (I'll only really speak about graphics as that is my area of expertise), these are a few of the choices you need to make EARLY in the project:

1) Is it an indoor and/or outdoor engine?
2) What sort of visibility system are you going to use?
3) Forward or deferred renderer?
4) How will you have animation hierarchies?
5) Dynamic or static lighting?
6) How are you going to handle transparency?
7) How will you handle a 2D overlay?
8) What mesh formats will you use?  Roll your own?

Bear in mind you need a GOOD solid vector/matrix library and preferably a full maths library that will help with things from eulers to quaternions to axis-aligned bounding boxes.

Do a lot of research as well.  Try to find out what the potential problems you are going to face are.  Remember things like changing a texture or a shader can have HUGE impacts on your pipelining.  You need to minimise these as much as possible.

Bear in mind that getting a rotating bump mapped mesh on the screen is simple by comparison to getting an engine running.  Don't let this put you off.  It should be no problem to write a fairly simple game rendering engine in a matter of months :)

Also ... find communities specific to this area.  You will get a lot of good (though non-OpenGL-centric) information off [DirectXDev](http://discussms.hosting.lsoft.com/SCRIPTS/WA-MSD.EXE?A0=DIRECTXDEV).  There is a fair bit of general game development algorithm information available at [GDAlgorithms](https://lists.sourceforge.net/lists/listinfo/gdalgorithms-list).  There is also an OpenGL specific mailing list [here](http://tech.groups.yahoo.com/group/opengl-gamedev-l/).

Its worth noting that DirectXDev and GDAlgorithms, at least (I don't know so much on the GL mailing list) are populated by some VERY experienced 3D engine and game developers.  Don't post up lots of "beginner" questions as this does tend to breed contempt among the members.  Though the odd query or 2 at whatever level (beginner to advanced) will get amazing answers.

Good luck!  I wish I'd had the chance to do this at University.  I might not have gone off and joined the games industry and enjoyed an extra year of sleeping late ;) hehehe

Answer (score 3):

Why do you need *any* C++ code?

There are already several wrapper libraries exposing OpenGL or DirectX to .NET, such as [SlimDX](http://slimdx.org/) (which, as the name implies, is a much thinner, more light-weight wrapper than something like XNA)

If you're more comfortable with C#, there's no reason why you couldn't write your entire game in that.

Performance generally won't be a problem. In most cases, the performance of C# code is comparable to C++. Sometimes it's faster, sometimes it's slower. But there are few cases where C# isn't *fast enough*. (However, there is a significant performance cost to interfacing between native and .NET code -- so doing that too often will hurt performance -- so the trick is, if you use native code at all, to have sufficiently big native operations, so the jump to/from .NET isn't done *too* often)

Apart from that, a word of advice: [Don't bother writing an "engine"](http://scientificninja.com/advice/write-games-not-engines).
You'll be wasting your time producing a big monolithic chunk of code which, ultimately, doesn't work, because it was never tested against the requirements of an *actual* game, only what you *thought* your future game would need.

If you want to experiment with game development, make a *game*. And then, by all means, refactor it and clean it up and try to extract reusable parts of the code. But if the code hasn't already been used in a game, you won't be able to use it to build a game in the future either.

The engines used in commercial games are just this, code extracted from previous games, code which has been tested, and which *works*.
By contrast, hobbyist engines pretty much always end up taking 2+ years of the developer's time, without ever offering anything usable.

The whole concept of a  "game engine" is flawed. In *every* other field of software development, you'd frown at the idea of *one* vaguely-defined component doing basically "everything I need to make my product". You'd be especially suspicious of the idea that it is a separate entity that can be developed *separate* from the actual product it's supposed to support.

Only in game development, which is by and large stuck in 80's methodologies, is it a common approach. Even though it doesn't actually work.

If this is a school project, I'm sure whoever is supposed to grade it will appreciate it if you apply common good software practices to the field. Just because many newcomers to game development don't do that (and prefer to stick to some kind of myth about "engines"), there's no reason why you shouldn't do better.

Comment: Good answer if he wasn't doing this for a school project.  Since he is, this is much less applicable since the end result is expected to be an engine.

Comment: True, but in a school project, you are still expected to produce something that *makes sense*. Any sane definition of a "game engine" includes "must support the development of a game". And at least in my school projects, I've always been expected to make something that *fulfills its purpose*. In other words, if you make a game engine which isn't useful in making games, who is it going to impress? Whether or not it is actually *used* to make games is less relevant, but it should be *capable* of that job. And there is no way it'll achieve that, if it is designed as a standalone "engine".

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your scope is feasible.

As a teenager I went through the build-my-own-engine phase, a few years later I realized I would have gotten a whole lot more done if I had just used pygame and pyopengl and not wasted the effort.

Check out the forums at gamedev.net.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds to me like you have a pretty good plan for your project. (I get your point about XNA in your comment to @Meeh)

You can interop with C++ via P/Invoke directly or COM, you could also I guess come up with some SOA way of doing it, but to be honest as yucky as this sounds I would be inclined to target COM as your API lever of choice...why? because then you open up your API to a lot of common client language's not just C# and VB.NET you will also get Delphi, VBA, Powerbuilder etc.

Performance should not be a problem as the API entry points are just to kick of the work and transport data structures, the real work is done in your library in native code, so don't worry too much about the perf. ATL will be your friend with creating COM Classes that provide entry to your Library.

Answer (score 0):

Whilst it's certainly do-able to bridge between C++ and C# (Via managed C++ is a good way to go if the interface is complex, P/Invoke for a very simple one), for tool<->engine communication I might suggest instead a network based interface. This is ideal for a high-ish level interface, such as you might want for a level editor/model viewer or such. An actual object modeller is not such a good target. What tools do you envision?

If you do it this way you gain the ability to connect to remote instances of the engine, or multiple instances, or even instances running on different hardware platforms. It'll also teach you a bit about sockets if you don't know them already.